# Remove a '\n' list item from a list of a reading file

Tags: python

I have a similar problem. My code so far is:

```
file='/Users/Giannis/Desktop/Python Assegments/Week 6/boardlist1.txt'
boardlist = []

file = open(file, 'r')
line = file.readlines()
wordstring = ''

for i in range(0,len(line)):

    final_list = []
    raw = list(line[i])
    boardlist.append(raw)

print(boardlist)

file.close()
```

The file you see is a txt which is:

```
EFJAJCOWSS 
SDGKSRFDFF 
ASRJDUSKLK 
HEANDNDJWA 
ANSDNCNEOP 
PMSNFHHEJE 
JEPQLYNXDL
```

My print results are:

```
[['E', 'F', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'C', 'O', 'W', 'S', 'S', '\n'], ['S', 'D', 'G', 'K', 'S', 'R', 'F', 'D', 'F', 'F', '\n'], ['A', 'S', 'R', 'J', 'D', 'U', 'S', 'K', 'L', 'K', '\n'], ['H', 'E', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'J', 'W', 'A', '\n'], ['A', 'N', 'S', 'D', 'N', 'C', 'N', 'E', 'O', 'P', '\n'], ['P', 'M', 'S', 'N', 'F', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'J', 'E', '\n'], ['J', 'E', 'P', 'Q', 'L', 'Y', 'N', 'X', 'D', 'L']]
```

And I want to remove every `\n` character in it. How can I do that with this code?

Comment: try `line = line.replace('\n','')` before `for` loop

Comment: use strip() raw = list(line[i].strip())

Comment: Apart from the recommendations above, your code can be significantly improved. Take a look at the `with` Python keyword and `looping` techniques.

Comment: How can i do this? I am new here. How can i see the with Python kewword and looping techniques?

Answer (score 3):

Use `strip()`, here is the shortest version of your code :

```
file='/Users/Giannis/Desktop/Python Assegments/Week 6/boardlist1.txt'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    print([list(i) for i in [i.strip() for i in f]])
[['E', 'F', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'C', 'O', 'W', 'S', 'S'], ['S', 'D', 'G', 'K', 'S', 'R', 'F', 'D', 'F', 'F'], ['A', 'S', 'R', 'J', 'D', 'U', 'S', 'K', 'L', 'K'], ['H', 'E', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'J', 'W', 'A'], ['A', 'N', 'S', 'D', 'N', 'C', 'N', 'E', 'O', 'P'], ['P', 'M', 'S', 'N', 'F', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'J', 'E'], ['J', 'E', 'P', 'Q', 'L', 'Y', 'N', 'X', 'D', 'L']]
```

Note : You don't need to use `readlines()`, just iterate the file object.

Comment: In fact i need to read my file from a text. Where exactly i have to put this part of code? It shows me error when i put it under the for loop. I think strip is my solution but i don't know how to use it and where exactly in the code.

Comment: I have shorten your code, therefore you don't need to worry about your code, just use my code as it is.

Comment: No i need to return a list of lists of strings as my results without the \n characters

Comment: edited, check my answer, I have formatted it as list of list